# Не удаётся правильно сериализовать List<Class> в Xml

Tags: c#, serialize

Не получается нормально сериализовать в Xml.

Десериализация:

```
string namesDB = string.Format(@"{0}namesDB.xml", saveDir);

        XmlSerializer serial = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<PersonClass>));
        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(namesDB))
        {
            persList = serial.Deserialize(stream) as List<PersonClass>;
        }
        foreach (var item in persList)
        {
            DataRow newRow = personDataTable.NewRow();
            newRow[0] = item.фамилияИнициалы;
            newRow[1] = item.имя;
            newRow[2] = item.отчество;
            newRow[3] = item.фамилия;
            newRow[4] = item.местонахождение;
            personDataTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
        }
```

Сериализация:

```
List<PersonClass> checkPersonList = new List<PersonClass>();
        for (int j = 0; j < personDataTable.Rows.Count; j++)
        {
            List<string> tempList = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < personDataTable.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                tempList.Add(personDataTable.Rows[j].ItemArray[i].ToString());
            }
            checkPersonList.Add(new PersonClass(tempList[3], tempList[1], tempList[2]));
        }
        bool persDiff = false;
        if (persList.Count == checkPersonList.Count)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < persList.Count; i++)
            {
                if (!persList[i].Equals(checkPersonList[i]))
                {
                    persDiff = true;
                }
            }
        }
        else
            persDiff = true;

        if (persDiff)
        {
            if (DialogResult.Yes == MessageBox.Show("Сохранить изменения?", "Сохранение", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo))
            {
                string namesDB = string.Format(@"{0}namesDB2.xml", saveDir);
                XmlSerializer serial = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<PersonClass>));
                using (var stream = File.OpenWrite(namesDB))
                {
                    serial.Serialize(stream, checkPersonList); //Ломает xml
                }
            }
            string checkFile = string.Format(@"{0}namesDB2.xml", saveDir);

            //Проверка не сломался ли xml
            string myText = "";
            using (var rdr = new StreamReader(checkFile))
            {
                myText = rdr.ReadToEnd();
            }
            MatchCollection coll = Regex.Matches(myText, @"ArrayOfPersonClass");
            if (coll.Count > 2)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("xml сериализован не правильно");
            }
        }
```

Код класса:

```
public class PersonClass
{
    public string фамилия = "";
    public string имя = "";
    public string отчество = "";
    public string фамилияИнициалы = "";
    public string местонахождение = "";

    public PersonClass()
    {

    }

    public PersonClass(string Фамилия, string Имя, string Отчество)
    {
        this.имя = Имя;
        this.фамилия = Фамилия;
        this.отчество = Отчество;
        фамилияИнициалы = string.Format(@"{0} {1} {2}", Фамилия, !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Имя) ? Имя.Substring(0, 1) : null, !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Отчество) ? Отчество.Substring(0, 1) : null);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        PersonClass qqe = obj as PersonClass;
        if (qqe == null)
            return false;
        return (имя == qqe.имя) && (фамилия == qqe.фамилия) && (отчество == qqe.отчество) && (фамилияИнициалы == qqe.фамилияИнициалы) && (местонахождение == qqe.местонахождение);
    }
```

Если в DataGridView удалить строки, то получается такая ошибка в xml(Ошибка проявляется не всегда. Когда точно, я до сих пор не понял):

```
</ArrayOfPersonClass>я>Юрий</имя>
<отчество>Геннадьевич</отчество>
<фамилияИнициалы>Фролов Ю Г</фамилияИнициалы>
<местонахождение />
</PersonClass>
```

Должно быть:

```
<PersonClass>
<фамилия>Кулаев</фамилия>
<имя>Андрей</имя>
<отчество>Александрович</отчество>
<фамилияИнициалы>Кулаев А А</фамилияИнициалы>
<местонахождение />
</PersonClass>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша проблема - в том, что `File.OpenWrite` не затирает старый файл, а пишет поверх. Если количество записываемой информации уменьшается - в файле остается мусор.

Используйте вызов `File.Open(namesDB, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)`.

Comment: Спасибо, плохо не знать таких мелочей.